# Is it possible to animate JPGs?

Tags: images, animated, gif

This may sound ridiculous, but I'm curious as to how this image on imgur is animated: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKpFR.gif and yet still appears to be a JPG file, not a GIF.

Is it server side? It's viewing the straight file, and so it can be using any JavaScript or other to fulfill this.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's just a GIF image file that had the extension changed to JPG, no javascript involved.

Comment: You can determine the file type by viewing the image meta information in photoshop and other graphic editing programs. If you want to animate a JPG you can use parallax design

Comment: @Anagio ...or the Content-Type HTTP response header as received by the browser (assuming the server is sending the correct headers). In this case "image/gif".